# Facebook API - Search for users by name without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I need to search for certain users on Facebook by their names(ex. Full name or First_name). Is it possible to do that without having access token for user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cant do that,

Atmost, you can search for User object (note, that you MUST provide search type) (will include everything related with jashwant)

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jashwant
```

but this

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jashwant&type=user
```

append access_token to requested URL.

Comment: And There's no way to get an access token unless the user logged in, right?